# Overlapping text decorations

Tags: css

```
<span id="case1" class="comment>text text</span>
<span id="case2" class="suggestion">suggestion</span>
<span id="case3" class="comment>text text <span class="suggestion">suggestion suggestion</span> text text</span>
```

I would like `span.comment` to have a dotted red underline, `span.suggestion` to have a dotted yellow underline and `span` with both `.comment` and `.suggestion` to have a dotted red/yellow underline (one dot red, one dot yellow, one dot red etc.)

What should my CSS look like? Is it possible with text-decoration or border-bottom? Should I use transparent images?

Comment: There is no question here.  A questions end with a question mark (?).  This is "plz send teh codez"

Comment: I have no idea how to solve this. I hoped someone would at least steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dotted underlines can be done with a border style:

```
span.comment {border-bottom: dotted 1px red;}
span.suggestion {border-bottom: dotted 1px yellow;}
```

However, the both yellow and red underline cant be done with only CSS. I suggest simplifying it to one color (i.e. orange)

Answer (score 0):

Using nested `<span>`s you can create a dashed border with alternating colors:

```
<span style="border-bottom: 3px solid #ff0">
  <span style="border-bottom: 3px dashed #f00">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
  </span>
</span>
```

It would be a bit harder to do with dots, though.